# os.getenv() is not pulling a variable I previously declare

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I cannot seem to figure out why I cannot get the `os.getenv()` function to work. It keeps returning `None` which is the default value if something is not there. Here is my code:

```
import os
import datetime
import plaid
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

PLAID_CLIENT_ID='entercharhere'
PLAID_ENV='sandbox'

#edit here
os.environ['PLAID_CLIENT_ID']='entercharhere'
os.environ['PLAID_ENV']='sandbox'

print(PLAID_CLIENT_ID)

# Fill in your Plaid API keys - https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('PLAID_CLIENT_ID')
# Use 'sandbox' to test with Plaid's Sandbox environment (username: user_good,
# password: pass_good)
# Use `development` to test with live users and credentials and `production`
# to go live
PLAID_ENV = os.getenv('PLAID_ENV','sandbox')

print(PLAID_CLIENT_ID)
```

The output I am receiving is `entercharhere` and `None`

**EDIT**

I wound up switching my declaration of variables to send them to the environment using this:

```
os.environ['PLAID_CLIENT_ID']='entercharhere'
os.environ['PLAID_ENV']='sandbox'
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Variables and environment variables are not the same thing.

Comment: What did you do to set PLAID_CLIENT_ID in the env?  Python globals are not env vars.

Comment: how do I set PLAID_CLIENT_ID in the environment? `export` does not seem to work and doesn't compile for me

Comment: The environment is usually set in the shell in which the python program's invoked.  However, if the program is invoked a different way, the mechanism to set the environment is usually different.

Comment: i wound up using `os.environ[]` Is this the best way to go about it if i'm running it straight from the .py script

Comment: Why read it at all? How do you plan to use `PLAID_CLIENT_ID` later? Is it needed by a subprocess?

Comment: did you use that *os.environ* in the same code and before using *os.getenv* ?

Comment: How did you use `os.environ`? I don't see how it would be any different than `os.getenv`?

Comment: I used `os.environ` in place of regular python global declaration

Answer (score -2):

Works perfectly:

```
import os

os.environ['SOMEVAR'] =  'bla'

print(os.getenv('SOMEVAR'))

# in your shell: export SOMEVAR1="blabla"
print(os.getenv('SOMEVAR1'))

Gives:
bla
blabla
```